# Remove top border of first child and bottom border of last child in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>FIRST</li>
<li>SECOND</li>
<li>THIRD</li>
<li>FOURTH</li>
<ul>
```

And the following CSS:

```
li
{
 border-top:1px solid #FFF;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;       
}​
```

How can I remove the top border for the first LI element, and the bottom border for the last LI element?
    ​

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
li:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}
li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Just like that.

Comment: Please note, that the CSS-selector ":last-child" only works in IE9 or greater. If you want to use this on IE8 and IE7 you could use "selectivizr" with a conditional statement "<!--[if lt IE 9]>", see: http://selectivizr.com

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS `:not` selector to apply styles only where required—rather than adding then removing them.

For example,

```css
body {
  background: #acc;
}

li:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

li:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Assuming you're [targeting modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3), this is the better answer.